# Botón de menú hamburguesa no se centra

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, navbar

**Hola a todos!**

Tengo un navbar que es adaptable a dispositivos. Le puse para que en el tamaño de telefóno estandar aparezca un botón de menú hamburguesa (toggle), pero el botón no se centra como se debería de centrar. Debería de centrarse al medio del navbar, pero se alinea abajo de este.

El contenedor del nav es flexbox y es responsive.

No tengo idea de porque pasa esto. Espero que me puedan ayudar!

Acá el código: (pongo el css así porque stack overflow me lo detecta como que es demasiado, aunque traté de compactarlo lo más que pude)

```js
$(".nav_togglebars").on("click", function() {    
               $('.navigation').show();
               $(".nav").css("height", "initial");
           });
```

```css
.nav  {
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          background: #0052a3;
          z-index: 1;
      } .nav .logo {
          margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
      } .nav .logo a {
          color: white;
      } .nav .logo, .navigation {
          list-style: none;
      } .nav .logo a, .navigation a {
          text-decoration: none;
      } .nav .navigation  {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin-right: 15px;
      } .nav .navigation a {
          font-size: 20px;
          display: block;
          margin-left: 24px;
          color: white;
          transition: 0.4s;
      } .nav .navigation a:hover {
          color: #f0f0f0;
      }.nav .navigation .button {
          color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 7px;
      }@media all and (max-width: 990px) {
          .nav {
            flex-direction: column;
          }.nav .logo {
            margin: 0;
          }.nav .navigation  {
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-around;
          }
      }@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
          .nav .logo {
            margin: .30em 0;
            display: inline;
            align-self: left;
            margin-bottom: 0;
          }.nav .navigation {
            flex-direction: column;
          }.nav .navigation a { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 8px;
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
          }.nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
            border-bottom: none;
          }
     } @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 900px) {
         .nav {
             height: 75px;
         }.nav .nav_togglebars {
             display: inline;
             padding: 0;
             align-self: flex-end;
             justify-content: center;
             color: white;
             margin-right: 1em;
             z-index: 1;
         }.nav .logo {
             margin-left: 0.5em;
         }.nav .navigation {
             display: none;
             margin-left: -3em;
         }
      
     }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav" style="">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
            <span class="nav_togglebars">m<i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Item</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución es poner el logo y el span con el botón dentro de un div con display:flex y width:100%.
Y quitar la altura 75px al bloque nav en el mediaquery.
De esta forma te quedan Logo y botón centrados en la barra superior.

Y como yo lo dejaría:

```
<style>
.nav  {
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
          background: #0052a3;
          z-index: 1;
      } 
.lin_logo{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}      
      
.nav .logo {
      margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
  } 
.nav .logo a {
      color: white;
  } 
.nav .logo, .navigation {
      list-style: none;
  } 
.nav .logo a, .navigation a {
      text-decoration: none;
  } 
.nav .navigation  {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-right: 15px;
  } 
.nav .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: 24px;
      color: white;
      transition: 0.4s;
  } 
.nav .navigation a:hover {
      color: #f0f0f0;
  }
.nav .navigation .button {
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 7px;
  }
@media all and (max-width: 990px) {

.nav .logo {
    margin: 0;
  }
.nav .navigation  {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.nav .logo {
    align-self: start;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
.nav .navigation {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.nav .navigation a { 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 8px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  }
.nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 900px) {
.nav .nav_togglebars {
    align-self: center;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1em;
    z-index: 1;
    }
.nav .logo {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    };
}
.nav .navigation {
             display: none;
             margin-left: -3em;
         }
      
}
</style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<html>

    <body>
        <div class="nav" >
        <div class="lin_logo">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
            <span class="nav_togglebars"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </div>    
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Item</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script>
$(".nav_togglebars").on("click", function() {    
               $('.navigation').show();
               $(".nav").css("height", "initial");
           });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy a probar y te aviso...

Comment: Funcionó! Te lo agradezco muchisimo